# Maximize All on a PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will essentially minimize all windows and show me my desktop. However, I have been unable to locate a similar shortcut key that either maximizes or restores all windows. Is there a pre-existing way to do this in Windows 7? I'd rather not mess with the BiOS if I don't have to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I doubt that it is really the answer that you are looking for, but on Windows 7, you could save this as a powershell script somewhere:

```
$dllInfo = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $dllInfo -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
foreach($proc in Get-Process){
    $hwnd = $proc.MainWindowHandle
    # Restore window
    [Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4) | Out-Null
}
```

Then bind a key to run that script.

Comment: This seems cool but a bit beyond me, unfortunately. +1 because this is basically exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about how to bind a key to run that script?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use Autohotkey.

Comment: Looks like this only maximizes *one* window from each process, right?

Comment: Yes it would only maximize the main window associated with that process.

Answer (score 11):

Use <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to restore minimized windows to the desktop.

Use <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to maximize the current window.

Use <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to maximize the window to the left side of the screen.

Use <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to maximize the window to the right side of the screen.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts#).

Comment: FYI: This only works for Windows Vista+

Comment: FYI : This is for win7 , see the source.

Comment: This is not actually an answer, is it?

Comment: @Daniel Beck; Well improve it ! , or answer the question yourself!;)

Comment: Sorry, but I agree with @Daniel Beck. How does this restore or maximize ALL windows? I just tried the first one, which was the most promising, and it did not work.

Comment: @KCotreau:  It works only when using first WinKey+ M

Comment: @binarylife It actually worked for me after Winkey+D. Didn't maximize, though.

Comment: @DanielBeck the first shortcut is working for me on Win 7 as it should like a charm.

Comment: @KronoS this works well in Win 7 as I've tried it myself.

Comment: @Aarthi it works after even when you press `Win+M` to minimize all windows and after that just press the first key combination suggested in the answer. Works well for me even I didn't press `Win+D`.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open `Windows Task Manager` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>).
2. Make sure the `Applications` tab is selected.
3. Go to the menu item `Windows`, then select `Maximize`.

This will maximize all windows regardless of their current state.

Comment: That was a new trick! Nice find

Comment: AFAIK this was the only way to maximize, cascade, or pile multiple minimized windows (very useful when you have DOZENS of instances from the same program) since you can select multiple applications using the "SHIFT" key.
Unfortunately, this "feature" is no longer possible starting with windows 8 and the new task manager

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. I am using a AutoHotkey script to only switch between windows of a single application(like in Mac). But the script only works on windows that are not minimized. This solves the problem of maximizing all windows but it requires too many steps. I wonder if there is any way of using some kind of script to program this to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

If you press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> *again*, it will restore all windows back to their previous state before you pressed <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the first time.  Works in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, you can toggle status of "only one window":

---

You can use WinKey+1, WinKey+2, ..., WinKey+9, WinKey+0 to toggle between minimized and restored status of each one of:

- the first 10 tasks in taskbar (including the not initialized ones but that are fixed in taskbar), when not showing tasks in groups

or

- the first 10 groups of tasks in taskbar (including the not initialized ones but that are fixed in taskbar), when showing tasks in groups - while holding WinKey, the list of tasks of a determined group related to number chosen is opened, clicking repeatedly in the same number chosen you can select a determined item in list and releasing WinKey you toggle status of chosen item in that group

Answer (score 1):

this is not 1 key but is faster than it looks.  Think you could do it with one key if you have AUTOHOTKEY, but I didn't bother.  Anyway:

1. launch task manager (I already have a desktop shortcut for this, define one if needed)
2. go to application tab if not already there (ctrl-pageup/ctrl-pagedown)
3. select all by press home, then ctrl-shift-end to select all (ctrl-a doesn't seem to work unfortunately)
4. shift-F10 (equivalent to right click)
5. X for maximize.

Note, unlike what you see in some posts, windows-shift-M does not maximize all, it is 'undo the previous minimize all', i.e. windows go back to how they were

Comment: AutoHotKey script (uses fact that ctrl-alt-U launches task manager via windows desktop shortcut).   
    
    ^!=::
    SetKeyDelay,1000
    Send ^!u
    SetKeyDelay,10
    Send {home}^+{end}
    Send +{F10}
    Send X
    return

Comment: you don't need to make a custom keyboard shortcut to launch the task manager on windows. Ctrl+Shift+Esc is the standard system defined keyboard shortcut to launch task manager in all versions of Windows and instead of Shift-F10 you could use the menu key that is on the left of the secondary ctrl key on the right side of most keyboards. Also thanks for the AutoHotKey script and this awesome tip.