# Is there a windows 7 shortcut to maximize all windows?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I've got many windows minimized in my taskbar and I'd like to maximize all of them at once. Is there a Windows 7 shortcut to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> does the trick

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/313248/maximize-all-on-a-pc?rq=1