# Maximized Windows are Unmaximized When Plugging In External Monitor

Tags: windows-7, extended-desktop

I have a laptop with Windows 7; I usually keep all my programs maximized (Firefox, Explorer, Notepad++), but whenever I connect my laptop to my external monitor for an extended display, all of my maximized windows are unmaximized. Is there a solution for this?

My problem is sort of similar to this (unanswered) one: [Resized maximized windows after screen resolution change](https://superuser.com/questions/237756/resized-maximized-windows-after-screen-resolution-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the resolution changes, thus Windows unmaximizes them.  There is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I have sort of a related issue. With the default setting for Notepad++ to open in a normal window, sometimes I cannot get it to maximize when I'm also connected to an external monitor for extended desktop/dual screen display.

This is annoying because I can't find a way to maximize Notepad++ without rebooting.

It looks like the fix is to change the Notepad++ shortcut to run in a maximized window. I will update if the issue reoccurs.

- Dell Latitude E5400
- Dell monitor P2310H

Answer (score 0):

You can use win+m to minimize all windows and after (dis)connecting the external display win+shift+m to restore them.